SSD outages for tens of seconds several times daily
It happens several times a day that a Samsung 980 PRO 2TB SSD [firmware 5B2QGXA7] stops working for a few seconds - applications that require disk access get stuck and resume after ~30s (very annoying).

Event Viewer: Windows logs\System  
Warning  20.9.2024 15:12:13  iaStorAC  129  None
  Reset to device, \Device\RaidPort0, was issued.

Warning  20.9.2024 15:12:13  disk      153  None
  The IO operation at logical block address 0x3bce730 for Disk 0 (PDO name: \Device\00000048) was retried.


Warning  20.9.2024 15:50:47  iaStorAC  129  None
  Reset to device, \Device\RaidPort0, was issued.

Warning  20.9.2024 15:50:47  disk      153  None
  The IO operation at logical block address 0x30d9bd38 for Disk 0 (PDO name: \Device\00000048) was retried.


Samsung Magician S.M.A.R.T.
Description                              Raw Data    Status
Critical Warning                                0        OK
Temperature (K)                               306        OK
Available Spare                               100        OK
Available Spare Threshold                      10        OK
Percentage Used                                 1        OK
Data Units Read                          27132175        OK
Data Units Written                       40665412        OK
Host Read Commands                      793444454        OK
Host Write Commands                     695431537        OK
Controller Busy Time                         7881        OK
Power Cycles                                  743        OK
Power On Hours                               5919        OK
Unsafe Shutdowns                               19        OK
Media Errors                                    0        OK
Number of Error Information Log Entries         0        OK
Warning Composite Temperature Time              3        OK
Critical Composite Temperature Time             0        OK
Temperature Sensor 1                          306        OK
Temperature Sensor 2                          315        OK
Temperature Sensor 3                            0        OK
Temperature Sensor 4                            0        OK
Temperature Sensor 5                            0        OK
Temperature Sensor 6                            0        OK
Temperature Sensor 7                            0        OK
Temperature Sensor 8                            0        OK

The disk has about 120 GB free space.
Full Power Mode: Disabled
TRIM Status: Enabled
Over Provisioning: Disabled



Have you ever had such a problem, what could be the cause, and how to fix it?

Do you have one disk or two disks, I ask, because the error suggests you are using a RAID configuration

Certain IO operations do have a 30 second timeout in windows. When you see that behavior, it means something in the chain between windows/storage controller/raid/sata/SSD failed temporarily. You should immediately back up anything you don't want to lose before messing with it

You can try running Get-PhysicalDisk | Get-StorageReliabilityCounter | Format-List -Property * in powershell to see if there are any WriteErrorsTotal on that disk. The first thing I'd look at is whether there are any driver updates available from the PC manufacturer

I would like to emphasise the comment by Cpt.Whale to back up your data now. Then you could try re-seating the drive (with the computer switched off) to make sure the electrical connections to it are in good condition.

I have one disk only. The WriteErrorsTotal field is empty, the non empty fields are:
FlushLatencyMax: 5569, ReadLatencyMax: 67043, Temperature: 1, TemperatureMax: 1, Wear: 0, WriteLatencyMax: 66499. It happens for several months. I already tried reseating it - no change. There's just one position for SSD in the laptop. Could this be a sw problem or is it definitely a hw problem? Any other disk queries I can make?

You can get the SSD out, plug it into any USB-NVMe dongle, plug the dongle into a Windows machine and run CrystalDiskInfo to display full S.M.A.R.T. information. There should be corresponding utility under Linux as well.

Test your drive and provide the reports. That a good place to start. Asking if anyone else has had a problem doesn't actually solve anything for you, so don't bother asking that. Just ask the real question you need answered.

OK, S.M.A.R.T. data added

Currently, the disk D: has about ~120 GB, disk C: about 5MB (the result of running apps that took the space, usually about 1.5GB). I do know nothing about TRIM, but it's enabled according to SAMSUNG Magician.

Have you install Samsung Magician to check for firmware updates?  Your drive says the temperature is 306K or 188F, Your drive seems very hot, if it is NVMe I might consider a heat sink.
